# Difference between memory_order_consume and memory_order_acquire

Tags: c++, c, atomic, memory-model, stdatomic

I have a question regarding a [GCC-Wiki article](https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/Atomic/GCCMM/AtomicSync). Under the headline "Overall Summary" the following code example is given:

Thread 1:

```
y.store (20);
x.store (10);
```

Thread 2:

```
if (x.load() == 10) {
  assert (y.load() == 20)
  y.store (10)
}
```

It is said that, if all stores are **release** and all loads are **acquire**, the assert in thread 2 cannot fail. This is clear to me (because the store to x in thread 1 synchronizes with the load from x in thread 2).

But now comes the part that I don't understand. It is also said that, if all stores are **release** and all loads are **consume**, the results are the same. Wouldn't it be possible that the load from y is hoisted before the load from x (because there is no dependency between these variables)? That would mean that the assert in thread 2 actually can fail.

Comment: That part of the comment from the article doesn't apply to the code you posted.

Comment: Why not? The comment from the article refers to the code I posted. I only skipped the code from "Thread 3" (because that part was not relevant for this question).

Comment: The article literally tells you that the assert can fail when using Release/acquire mode: *d(), thread 3's assert can fail.*

Comment: @this But thread 3 is irrelevant for the OP's example. The article also says that *"The assert in thread 2 must still be true since thread 1 and 2 synchronize with x.load()"* when using release+acquire, and then *"If the stores are release and loads are consume the results are the same as release/acquire except there may be less hardware synchronization required."*

Comment: @dyp Yes. I clarified my question.

Comment: It is a pity that we have two almost equally highly upvoted answers here, which are contradicting.

Comment: @dyp That's true. But if someone reads both answers (and all comments), everything should be clear. Both answers are helpful and I am glad that this question is answered now.

Comment: @splotz90 I don't quite understand your point: If *Iwillnotexist*'s answer is correct, then (at least) half of Jens's answer is incorrect. Btw, I've sent the author of that GCC article an email, but either have I gotten the address wrong (weird SPAMFREE thing), or he hasn't responded yet.

Comment: @dyp What I meant is that Jens's code example is helpful to understand the difference between acquire and consume. But regarding this particular question, I also think that the explanation is not completely correct.

Thank you for sending an email. I hope he received the mail.

Comment: @dyp I am now even more certain of the correctness of my answer now that I've checked the code in question with a CppMem model. Everything is in an edit of my answer below.

Comment: @IwillnotexistIdonotexist Thank you for the prove. I didn't know this tool and I could not prove it on my machine (x86-64), because all loads are automatically acquire operations and all stores are automatically release operations on this architecture.

Comment: @dyp Any news from the GCC article author?

Comment: @IwillnotexistIdonotexist Unfortunately not. You might want to send an email yourself, which should decrease the risks of me getting the address wrong and the mail getting stuck in a spam filter.

Comment: @dyp I didn't get a reply yet but by searching through the mailing list I found [this email by one Paul E. Kenney](https://gcc.gnu.org/ml/gcc/2014-02/msg00369.html) with a discussion of a not-dissimilar example, and he believes the assert won't hold, citing exactly the same architectures (ARM and PowerPC) as a link within my answer below.

Comment: @IwillnotexistIdonotexist Wow that's a long thread. I quickly glanced over the linked email, but failed to find the second consume-load.

Comment: @dyp It's the `return b` statement in the first quoted code block, effectively. Immediately after said code block, he says," _The above example can have a return value of 0 if translated
straightforwardly into either ARM or Power, right?  Both of these can
speculate a read into a conditional, and both can translate a consume
load into a plain load if data dependencies remain unbroken._"

Comment: @IwillnotexistIdonotexist As far as I can tell, the `return b` is supposed to load `b` non-atomically (that's why the suggested alternative of using acquire makes sense). Jens Gustedt claims that there's a guaranteed order between two atomic consume-loads.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The C11 Standard's ruling is as follows.

#### 5.1.2.4 Multi-threaded executions and data races

> 15. An evaluation A is *dependency-ordered before* *16)* an evaluation B if:
>
>     — **A performs a release operation on an atomic object M, and, in another thread, B performs a consume operation on M and reads a value written by any side effect in the release sequence headed by A**, or
>
>     — for some evaluation X, A is dependency-ordered before X and X carries a dependency to B.
> 16. An evaluation A *inter-thread happens before* an evaluation B if A synchronizes with B, A is dependency-ordered before B, or, for some evaluation X:
>
>     — A synchronizes with X and X is sequenced before B,
>
>     — A is sequenced before X and X inter-thread happens before B, or
>
>     — A inter-thread happens before X and X inter-thread happens before B.
> 17. NOTE 7 The ‘‘inter-thread happens before’’ relation describes arbitrary concatenations of ‘‘sequenced before’’, ‘‘synchronizes with’’, and ‘‘dependency-ordered before’’ relationships, **with two exceptions**. The first exception is that **a concatenation is not permitted to end with ‘‘dependency-ordered before’’ followed by ‘‘sequenced before’’. The reason for this limitation is that a consume operation participating in a ‘‘dependency-ordered before’’ relationship provides ordering only with respect to operations to which this consume operation actually carries a dependency.** The reason that this limitation applies only to the end of such a concatenation is that any subsequent release operation will provide the required ordering for a prior consume operation. The second exception is that a concatenation is not permitted to consist entirely of ‘‘sequenced before’’. The reasons for this limitation are (1) to permit ‘‘inter-thread happens before’’ to be transitively closed and (2) the ‘‘happens before’’ relation, defined below, provides for relationships consisting entirely of ‘‘sequenced before’’.
> 18. An evaluation A *happens before* an evaluation B if A is sequenced before B **or** A inter-thread happens before B.
> 19. A *visible side effect A* on an object M with respect to a value computation B of M satisfies the conditions:
>
>     — **A happens before B, and**
>
>     — there is no other side effect X to M such that A happens before X and X happens before B.
>
>     The value of a non-atomic scalar object M, as determined by evaluation B, shall be the value stored by the visible side effect A.

*(emphasis added)*

---

*In the commentary below, I'll abbreviate below as follows:*

- *Dependency-ordered before:* **DOB**
- *Inter-thread happens before:* **ITHB**
- *Happens before:* **HB**
- *Sequenced before:* **SeqB**

---

Let us review how this applies. We have 4 relevant memory operations, which we will name Evaluations A, B, C and D:

Thread 1:

```
y.store (20);             //    Release; Evaluation A
x.store (10);             //    Release; Evaluation B
```

Thread 2:

```
if (x.load() == 10) {     //    Consume; Evaluation C
  assert (y.load() == 20) //    Consume; Evaluation D
  y.store (10)
}
```

To prove the assert never trips, we in effect seek to prove that *A is always a visible side-effect at D*. In accordance with *5.1.2.4* (15), we have:

> A  **SeqB**  B  **DOB**  C  **SeqB**  D

which is a concatenation ending in DOB followed by SeqB. This is *explicitly* ruled by (17) to **not** be an ITHB concatenation, despite what (16) says.

We know that since A and D are not in the same thread of execution, A is not SeqB D; Hence neither of the two conditions in (18) for HB is satisfied, and A does not HB D.

It follows then that A is not visible to D, since one of the conditions of (19) is not met. The assert may fail.

---

How this could play out, then, is described [here, in the C++ standard's memory model discussion](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2008/n2664.htm#control) and [here, Section 4.2 Control Dependencies](http://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/~pes20/ppc-supplemental/test7.pdf):

1. (Some time ahead) Thread 2's branch predictor guesses that the `if` will be taken.
2. Thread 2 approaches the predicted-taken branch and begins speculative fetching.
3. Thread 2 out-of-order and speculatively loads `0xGUNK` from `y` (Evaluation D). (Maybe it was not yet evicted from cache?).
4. Thread 1 stores `20` into `y` (Evaluation A)
5. Thread 1 stores `10` into `x` (Evaluation B)
6. Thread 2 loads `10` from `x` (Evaluation C)
7. Thread 2 confirms the `if` is taken.
8. Thread 2's speculative load of `y == 0xGUNK` is committed.
9. Thread 2 fails assert.

The reason why it is permitted for Evaluation D to be reordered before C is because a *consume* does *not* forbid it. This is unlike an *acquire-load*, which prevents any load/store *after* it in program order from being reordered *before* it. Again, 5.1.2.4(15) states, *a consume operation participating in a ‘‘dependency-ordered before’’ relationship provides ordering only with respect to operations to which this consume operation actually carries a dependency*, and there most definitely is not a dependency between the two loads.

---

### CppMem verification

[CppMem](http://svr-pes20-cppmem.cl.cam.ac.uk/cppmem/help.html) is a tool that helps explore shared data access scenarios under the C11 and C++11 memory models.

For the following code that approximates the scenario in the question:

```
int main() {
  atomic_int x, y;
  y.store(30, mo_seq_cst);
  {{{  { y.store(20, mo_release);
         x.store(10, mo_release); }
  ||| { r3 = x.load(mo_consume).readsvalue(10);
        r4 = y.load(mo_consume); }
  }}};
  return 0; }
```

The tool reports **two** consistent, race-free scenarios, namely:

> [image: Consume, Success Scenario]

In which `y=20` is successfully read, and

> [image: Consume, Failure Scenario]

In which the "stale" initialization value `y=30` is read. Freehand circle is mine.

By contrast, when `mo_acquire` is used for the loads, CppMem reports only **one** consistent, race-free scenario, namely the correct one:

> [image: Acquire, Success Scenario]

in which `y=20` is read.

Comment: This is really helpful! Thanks! I still have a dumb question, in the example you gave here, why can't we reason that operations A and D form a release/consume relation which, according to 15 and 16, can be considered that A inter-thread happens before D? In other words, why must we take operations B and C into consideration rather than reasoning only on A and D?

Comment: @PJ.Hades The example I gave with speculative loads is an example of why. Because the CPU is allowed to reorder the consumes C & D wrt each other (given neither carries a dependency to the other), D can conceivably happen long before A and B even _begin_. Therefore, C reading `10` does *not* constitute proof that D will read `20` (IOW, that sychronization always happens properly). The scenario you describe (A, D, B, C) would result in a correct sync, but the one I mention (D, A, B, C) is also possible under the same conditions.

Comment: It makes sense. I think I misunderstood something in the definition. Thanks for the explanation!

Answer (score 11):

Both establish a transitive "visibility" order on atomic stores, unless they have been issued with `memory_order_relaxed`. If a thread reads an atomic object `x` with one of the modes, it can be sure that it sees all modifications to all atomic objects `y` that were known to be done before the write to `x`.

The difference between "acquire" and "consume" is in the visibility of non-atomic writes to some variable `z`, say. For `acquire` *all* writes, atomic or not, are visible. For `consume` only the atomic ones are guaranteed to be visible.

```
thread 1                               thread 2
z = 5 ... store(&x, 3, release) ...... load(&x, acquire) ... z == 5 // we know that z is written
z = 5 ... store(&x, 3, release) ...... load(&x, consume) ... z == ? // we may not have last value of z
```

Comment: First of all thank you for your answer! Could you please give me a reference to the corresponding part of the C standard for the fact that all atomic writes are visible for consume?

Comment: Unless Anthony Williams is wrong in "C++ Concurrency in Action" p139-140, not **all** atomic writes are visible after `consume`. The example in Williams' book combines a relaxed atomic write/read with a release/consume operation, though. I don't quite see why that should be different for release/consume + release/consume, since the OP's example has no dependency ordering.

Comment: Hmm while that reconciles the example in the book with your answer, I don't quite understand how that is enforced in the specification. As far as I understand it, we need the synchronizes-with relationship between the stores and loads to `x` to invoke the "A synchronizes with X and X is sequenced before B" rule. But that isn't present for release/consume, and I can't see what other guarantee we have between the two stores in thread 1 besides the thread-internal *sequenced before*, which would also apply to non-atomic operations.

Comment: @splotz90, all of this is buried in the hard-to-digest section  5.1.2.4. In essence "consume" operations contribute to the "dependency-ordered before" relation. Whereas the "acquire" operations contribute to the "inter-thread happens before" relation, that is a superset of this. (And then `memory_order_seq_cst` is a total ordering of all this.)

Comment: @dyp, `memory_order_relaxed` operations are not among the synchronizing operation. There is an explanation in NOTE2 (that is p6) of the standard. They only guarantee consistency of the data, not synchronization.

Comment: I was referring to this particular example; your answer seems to suggest there's an exception from synchronisation for non-atomic writes and relaxed atomic writes, but I can't find any such exception in the spec (the dependency ordering even implies that some non-atomic writes become visible, even if they do not occur on the same object, e.g. the dependency that is carried in `p->x` from `p` to `p->x`). If there is no such exception, then there must be two distinct ways for rel+acq and rel+con, but I can't find a way for rel+con to establish the happens-before between the store and load to y.

Comment: I actually have the same problem to understand why the standard enforces a happens-before relation between the store to y and load from y.

Comment: @dyp The whole point of "synchronization" is have a past. W/o synchro there is no past and no future: things in other threads may be seen or maybe not. But even in the future are never seen and those in the past are always done. If non atomic events were not part of that "past" then object creation would never enter history and you couldn't even publish an object and expose it to another thread: even the most simple atomic publish idiom (in MT pseudo-code) `{x = new T; a.store(true);} ||| { if (a.load()) x->f(); }` would fail.

Comment: @curiousguy Woah, resurrecting a four-year-old thread, thanks for the nostalgia :D -- Indeed, I believe your example only holds for release+acq, but not for release+con nor for relaxed+anything on `a` - since there's no dependency ordering between `x = new T;` and `a.store(true)`. Modeling this on CppMem via `x = 42;` instead of `x = new T;` shows that release+acq is race free but the other two contain a data race. You need acq+rel or mutex etc to publish a new object. _"But even in the future are never seen and those in the past are always done."_ I don't get that sentence :(

Comment: @dyp If an event (a memory SE) is in our past, we will always "see" it: the effect is either testable or clobbered by another event that isn't older. An event in the future is never visible. An even in neither is potentially be seen. When you program w/ mutexes only (and no try_lock), you can use only the past, so stuff is clean. When you use atomics, you can see something before it's in the "past": you can test whether an atomic was changed by a parallel computation, which is a race. Then by acq (or another thread rel) you can put stuff in the past.

Comment: @dyp It should be possible to use consume for a new object, as it's a typical use case. But compiler writers have found it very difficult to get the correct consume semantics past the compiler front end in cases that might be optimized. (Linus wrote a list of problematic cases where compilers might break code data/addr dependencies in code that has read such "volatile" values: think `x[dep]` where `x` has type `int[1]` and `dep` has a "consume"-like value dependency.)

Comment: @curiousguy I have some trouble understanding the point you'd like to make, and maybe some more space (word limit) might help. So I've created this [chat room](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/203435/extended-discussion-difference-between-memory-order-consume-and-memory-order-acq).